# Does only prime numbers attend the form 6p+1 or 6p-1 ??

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computer-science

Some times before in a **Numberphile** video It was claimed that **every prime number is close to a multiple of 6** so they deduced that every prime number can be expressed as **6p+1** or **6p-1** but if we look closely most of the numbers which are **a square of prime number**(e.g $11^2$,$13^2$,$17^2$ ...)also attend the form **6p+1** so can we still call it a always true statement for creating a function or how to rectify the eror in the code ??

Comment: The numbers of the form $6k\pm1$ are precisely the numbers that are divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$. All primes greater than $3$ (and all their powers) fit this description. But the Numberphile video doesn't claim these are the only such numbers.

Comment: Then to program this statement  how to rectify the powers??

Comment: The statement is not wrong. Note that (almost) all primes are of the form $6k\pm1$ does not implies all numbers of the form $6k\pm1$ are primes. Cars have wheels doesn't mean that everything that has wheels is a car.

Comment: @player3236, Are there any composites (other than the squares of primes) that are of the form $6k \pm 1$ ? If no, I have an answer.

Comment: @Spectre Any number with only factors of the form $6k\pm1$ fits. These are also all the numbers that are coprime to $6$. The smallest not-prime-power is $35$.

Comment: In short, other kinds of composites also appear when using $6k \pm 1$, is that so, @player3236 ?

Comment: @player3236, here's something I put in GitHub : https://github.com/Coder-X15/Sorter/wiki/Sorter-----an-Overview-of-My-Intention

Comment: The code there has it all, I think.

Comment: @MaharshiMahanti , you may also look through this : https://github.com/Coder-X15/CmdPrime

Comment: @Spectre Yes, plenty of other kinds of composites have the form $6k \pm 1$--namely, everything whose prime factorization doesn't include any 2's or 3's.

Comment: BTW, what about my code projects there, @RaviFernando ? I forgot the fact that I had better answers there.

Comment: @Spectre What about them?  Based on the descriptions, they look like applications of Wilson's theorem and (a version of) the sieve of Eratosthenes respectively.  In any case, I think the comments above (from Greg Martin and player3236) fully answer this question.  I'm not sure what more needs to be said.

Comment: @RaviFernando , even I felt so. But the OP is looking for some code as well, so I just put them up for reference.

Comment: In fact, everything that can be said has been said about this question. It is very easy to show that a number is of the form $6p \pm 1$ if and only if it is neither divisible by $2$ nor by $3$ and not only the squares of primes , but EVERY product of primes greater than $3$ is of this form. So, exploiting this property is still very far away from a primality test.

Comment: Since the question was basically whether ONLY primes (or squares of primes) have this property , mentioning the criterions for prime numbers or even primality tests would probably be somewhat off-topic. There are enough questions on this site for those interested in these topics.